# Understanding the 4 fundamental subspaces for a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Wondering if there is anything cool to see in the fundamental subspace picture for an $n \times n$ matrix that is different from the $m \times n$ case? Can this picture be related to the existence of an inverse?.

I can see that the row and column spaces are not in general orthogonal as membership is not mutually exclusive as in the $m \times n$ case. For example $I_{2}$ has an identical row and column space as $I_{2}^{T} = I_{2}$.

i.e., $A=A^{T} \iff span\{col(A)\} = span\{row(A)\}$.

In general I suppose the vector space made by $C(A)\cap C(A^{T})= span\{0, col(A) : col(A) \in col(A^{T})\}$ by definition.

Clearly the left nullity has the same size as the nullity, and if the matrix is not full rank, then they both must contain more than the $0$ vector. As usual, $N(A^{T})\cap C(A) = \{0\}$ and $N(A)\cap C(A^{T}) = \{0\}$.

Anything else interesting to draw from this picture?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything more interesting than the relations coming from $N(A^*) = R(A)^{\perp}$. One other thing is that if $X, Y$ are subspaces of the domain and codomain of $A$ respectively and $A^* : Y \to X$, then $A : X^\perp \to Y^\perp$. This is trivial to prove, but comes up in linear algebra proofs.